# Using Spring Web-flow and trying to use Spring AjaxEventDecoration to kick off transitions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am using  Spring Web-flow and trying to use Spring AjaxEventDecoration to kick off transitions. but something is going on that this code is not running

```
<tr>
            <td><label>Borough</label></td>
            <td><select id="borough" name="borough">
                <option value="UNKNOWN">Unknown</option>
                <option value="X">Bronx</option>
                <option value="K">Brooklyn</option>
                <option value="M">Manhattan</option>
                <option value="Q">Queens</option>
                <option value="R">Staten Island</option>
                <option value="O">All Other Schools</option>
            </select>

<script type="text/javascript" src='<c:url value="/resources/spring/Spring.js" />'> </script>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
                        elementId : "borough",
                        formId : "member",
                        event : "onChange",
                        params : {
                            _eventId : "loadSchools",
                            fragments : "body"
                        }
                    }));
                </script>


            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: If javascript is not running it's because it has an error. Check if you can access `/resources/spring/Spring.js` from the browser and then make sure you've written the `Spring.addDecoration(...)` correctly.

Comment: yes from the browser Spring.js is downloading